# WebDriverException:Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Plz help me.
I write a program to login linkedin and share something by using selenium.
But after login, I want to share something but I meet a problem:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: {"errorMessage":"Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: \"script-src 'report-sample' 'sha256-6gLjSWp3GRKZCUFvRX5aGHtECD1wVRgJOJp7r0ZQjV0=' 'unsafe-inline' static.licdn.com s.c.lnkd.licdn.com static-fstl.licdn.com static-src.linkedin.com https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/service-worker-push.js https://platform.linkedin.com/js/analytics.js static-exp1.licdn.com static-exp2.licdn.com s.c.exp1.licdn.com s.c.exp2.licdn.com static-lcdn.licdn.com s.c.lcdn.licdn.com https://www.linkedin.com/sc/ https://www.linkedin.com/scds/ https://qprod.www.linkedin.com/sc/ https://www.linkedin.com/sw.js https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/abp-detection.js\".\n","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"291","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:14248","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_60)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"script\":\"var x=document.getElementsByClassName(\\\"mentions-texteditor__contenteditable\\\");x[0].innerHTML=\\\"<p>That's far more painful than a record-keeping God up in the skies.<br></p>\\\";\",\"args\":[{\"ELEMENT\":\":wdc:1515140075880\",\"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf\":\":wdc:1515140075880\"}]}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/6160fa40-f1f0-11e7-9786-bb95dc5c4adc/execute"}}
Command duration or timeout: 1.96 seconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:671)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:573)
    at com.gaodig.linkedin.LinkedInOps.shareSth(LinkedInOps.java:125)
    at com.gaodig.linkedin.LinkedInOps.main(LinkedInOps.java:219)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:141)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: {"errorMessage":"Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: \"script-src 'report-sample' 'sha256-6gLjSWp3GRKZCUFvRX5aGHtECD1wVRgJOJp7r0ZQjV0=' 'unsafe-inline' static.licdn.com s.c.lnkd.licdn.com static-fstl.licdn.com static-src.linkedin.com https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/service-worker-push.js https://platform.linkedin.com/js/analytics.js static-exp1.licdn.com static-exp2.licdn.com s.c.exp1.licdn.com s.c.exp2.licdn.com static-lcdn.licdn.com s.c.lcdn.licdn.com https://www.linkedin.com/sc/ https://www.linkedin.com/scds/ https://qprod.www.linkedin.com/sc/ https://www.linkedin.com/sw.js https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/abp-detection.js\".\n","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"291","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:14248","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_60)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"script\":\"var x=document.getElementsByClassName(\\\"mentions-texteditor__contenteditable\\\");x[0].innerHTML=\\\"<p>That's far more painful than a record-keeping God up in the skies.<br></p>\\\";\",\"args\":[{\"ELEMENT\":\":wdc:1515140075880\",\"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf\":\":wdc:1515140075880\"}]}","url":"/execute","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"execute","directory":"/","path":"/execute","relative":"/execute","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/execute","queryKey":{},"chunks":["execute"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/6160fa40-f1f0-11e7-9786-bb95dc5c4adc/execute"}}
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MS-20161025GMIQ', ip: '10.76.124.130', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

My code:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.ByCssSelector.cssSelector(".sharing-create-share-view__create-content>button"));
ele.click();
String content = shareContent[new Random().nextInt(shareContent.length)];
String setContentJS = "var x=document.getElementsByClassName(\"mentions-texteditor__contenteditable\");x[0].innerHTML=\"<p>"+content+"<br></p>\";";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
ele = driver.findElement(By.ByCssSelector.cssSelector(".mentions-texteditor__contenteditable"));
js.executeScript(setContentJS, ele); // GET EXCEPTION
MyWebDriverUtils.mySleep(1, 1);
driver.findElement(By.ByCssSelector.cssSelector(".sharing-share-box__post-button")).click();
```

selenium-java:3.4.0
 phantomjsdriver:1.3.0
 phantomjs:2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of content you used? Did you try a simple string (not include any html tag) as the value of content, like 'test'.

And the second argument `ele` is unnecessary in `js.executeScript(setContentJS, ele);`,  because there is no any argument placehold: arguments[x] in `setContentJS`

Try below code

```
String content = "Test 1234";
String setContentJS = "arguments[0].innerHTML=arguments[1]";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
ele = driver.findElement(By.ByCssSelector.cssSelector(".mentions-texteditor__contenteditable"));
js.executeScript(setContentJS, ele, content);
```

If above code still not work, please try to change the innerHTML of the element manualy in DevTool's console Tab, to see it will archive your goal or not.

Comment: Thank you very much!The content is modified to a simple string now. And I change my code as you say.But it is the same problem.